# Angular routes returns 404 error in google lighthouse

Tags: angular, routes, lighthouse

I have an angular website, its running all good on the cloud and locally but when I tested it using lighthouse in google chrome all the test failed because it returning 404 pages, which I can't detect, so I run the build localy using `http-server` to test it, this time I saw a difference in the results but still getting 404 error, but this time is my homepage.

In the angular project I have configured the routes to redirect '' to '/home/shop' and it does and its found, but when reload again on the route '/home/shop' it says not found and I have to delete this and get back to the homepage by hitting the empty path ''.

Please note that this behavior only when I deployed my project.

It would be great if someone helped me to configure my routes in my project to retrieve the home page without any redirecting.

Here is my routes:

```
export const rootRouterConfig: Routes = [
  { 
    path: '', 
    redirectTo: 'home/shop', 
    pathMatch: 'full' 
  },
  { 
    path : '',
    component : MainComponent,
    children: [ 
      {
        path : 'home',
        loadChildren: './shop/shop.module#ShopModule'
      },
      { 
        path: 'pages',
        loadChildren: './pages/pages.module#PagesModule'
      },
      { 
        path: 'blog',
        loadChildren: './blog/blog.module#BlogModule'
      }
    ]
  },
  { 
    path: '**', 
    redirectTo: 'pages/404'
  }
];
```

and here is the sub routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: 'shop',
    component: HomeFiveComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'collection/:category/:subCategory',
    component: CollectionLeftSidebarComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'right-sidebar/collection/:category',
    component: CollectionRightSidebarComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'no-sidebar/collection/:category',
    component: CollectionNoSidebarComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'product/:id',
    component: ProductLeftSidebarComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'right-sidebar/product/:id',
    component: ProductRightSidebarComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'no-sidebar/product/:id',
    component: ProductNoSidebarComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'col-left/product/:id',
    component: ProductColLeftComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'col-right/product/:id',
    component: ProductColRightComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'column/product/:id',
    component: ProductColumnComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'accordian/product/:id',
    component: ProductAccordianComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'left-image/product/:id',
    component: ProductLeftImageComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'right-image/product/:id',
    component: ProductRightImageComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'vertical/product/:id',
    component: ProductVerticalTabComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'search',
    component: SearchComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'wishlist',
    component: WishlistComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'compare',
    component: ProductCompareComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'cart',
    component: CartComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'checkout',
    component: CheckoutComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'checkout/success',
    component: SuccessComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ShopRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

as a quick fix try HashLocationStrategy

add this to app.module.ts

```
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy  } from '@angular/common';

providers: [
       {provide : LocationStrategy , useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
  ],
```

https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy#methods

this works for me

Note: if you are using dns masking this might not work.